# Eclipse Java Build Path not allowing Add External JARs

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

When creating a new Java project, I am attempting to add an external JAR. When I click on the **Add External JARs**... button in the Libraries tab, the screen dialog flashes and nothing happens.

I am able to click on all other buttons, which work completely fine.

Has anyone else seen this issue before?

I have already tried closing the project and reopening. I have also gone through the normal steps multiple times by right clicking on the **Project** and going to either **Properties** or **Build Path** > **Configure Build Path...**.

Comment: try to restart eclipse? seems eclipse in wrong state

Comment: I tried this and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Any exception on `.metadata/.log` file?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Addendum : [workspace]/.metadata/.log file

Comment: I am not seeing any log file here. under [workspace]/.metadata, I have .mylyn, .plugins folders. as well as a .lock and a version.ini file. no log.